# How to display searching data on the same link of page on PHP by clicking a submit button?

Tags: php, html, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjmP6.png)

Hi Guys, I have the following problem:

In the url

> "/media.php?module=riwayat&noreg=00020517"

All data with 'noreg = 00020517' is displayed. I want to filter the displayed data with 'keyword' entered in the textbox after the 'cari' button is clicked. How to without change the url?

the code on 'riwayat.php' is:

```
switch($_GET[act]){
        default:
$aksi="modul/riwayat/aksi_riwayat.php";
$table  = 'pasien';
$noreg  = $_GET[noreg];
$text   = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE noreg = $noreg";
$sql1   = mysql_query($text);
$row1   = mysql_num_rows($sql1);
echo "<div id='dalam_content'>
<h2>RIWAYAT PASIEN</h2>
    <div id='info_pasien'>
";
        if ($row1>0){
        while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){        
        $lahir  =new DateTime($r['tgl_lahir']);
        // Convert Ke Date Time
        $today      = new DateTime();
        $umur = $today->diff($lahir);
        echo "
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>NO REG.</b></td>
                    <td><b>:   $r[noreg]</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nama</b></td>
                    <td><b>:   $r[nama_pasien]</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tgl Lahir</b></td>
                    <td><b>:   ".jin_date_str($r[tgl_lahir])."</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jenis Kelamin</b></td>
                    <td><b>:   $r[kelamin]</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Alamat</b></td>
                    <td><b>:   $r[alamat]</b></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td>UMUR</b></td>
                    <td><b>:     "; echo $umur->y; echo " Tahun, "; echo $umur->m; echo " Bulan, dan "; echo $umur->d; echo " Hari";   echo "</b></td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
    </div>";
        }}
        echo"
    <div id='tampil_data1'>
        <div id='tombol-cari'>
            <form method=POST action='$aksi?module=riwayat&act=cari' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input name=kata type=text size=23 maxlength=50 />
            <input type=submit value=Cari>
            <input type=hidden name=noreg value=$noreg>
            </form>
            <input type=button value='Pemeriksaan Baru' onclick=\"window.location.href='?module=riwayat&act=periksabaru&noreg=$noreg';\">
        </div>
            <table id='theTable' width='100%'>
                <tr>
                    <th width='10%'>Tanggal</th>
                    <th>Pemeriksaan</th>
                    <th>Terapi</th>
                </tr>";
                $kata = trim($_POST['kata']);
                $kata = htmlentities(htmlspecialchars($kata), ENT_QUOTES);
                $table2 = 'riwayat';
                $where3 = "WHERE noreg= $noreg AND pemeriksaan LIKE '%$kata%' OR terapi LIKE '%$kata%'";
                $sql3   = "SELECT * FROM $table2 $where3    ORDER BY id ASC";
                $query3 = mysql_query($sql3);
                while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query3)){
                    if ($kata==$kata){
                    $pemeriksaan=$rows[pemeriksaan];
                    $pemeriksaan = preg_replace( "/$kata/i", '<span style="background-color:yellow;">' . $kata . '</span>', $pemeriksaan );
                    $terapi=$rows[terapi];
                    $terapi = preg_replace( "/$kata/i", '<span style="background-color:yellow;">' . $kata . '</span>', $terapi );
                    }
                else {
                    $pemeriksaan=$rows[pemeriksaan];
                    $terapi=$rows[terapi];
                }
                    echo "
                <tr>

                    <td align='center'>".jin_date_str($rows[tgl_periksa])."</td>
                    <td>$pemeriksaan</td>
                    <td>$terapi</td>
                </tr>";

                }
                echo "
            </table>";
    break;
```

and the 'aksi_riwayat.php' code is:

```
$module=$_GET[module];
$act=$_GET[act];
$noreg= $_POST[noreg];
// Input pemeriksaanbaru
if ($module=='riwayat' AND $act=='input'){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO riwayat(tgl_periksa,
                                noreg,
                                pemeriksaan,
                                terapi) 
                        VALUES('$_POST[tgl]',
                               '$_POST[noreg]',
                               '$_POST[pemeriksaan]',
                               '$_POST[terapi]')");


  header('location:../../media.php?module=riwayat&noreg='.$noreg);
 }
// Input Cari
elseif ($module=='riwayat' AND $act=='cari'){
header('location:../../media.php?module=riwayat&noreg='.$noreg);
}
```

Comment: You want to filter the results returned?

Comment: yes with the keyword on textfield 'kata'

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AJAX** for this purpose.
After click on Submit button you have to pass data to server and get back response from server end. Once you get data you have to render on target position.

[This link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) will give you better idea how  you can integrate AJAX.

The following is sample code from the above link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
        {
          name: "Donald Duck",
          city: "Duckburg"
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

If anymore doubt please let me know.